# bash - load variables from script to main shell

Tags: bash

How would you go about loading variables declared into a script, into the main shell?

For example, I have a script that grabs credentials from a web page (example), and I would like those credentials to be available to the main shell that ran the script.

So far I tried exporting the variable, like:

```
export uvar="user"
export pvar="password"
```

This doesn't work outside of the script.

Then I tried sending these vars out to a file and then sourcing that file, then removing the file, like so:

```
echo 'uvar="user"' >> /tmp/testfile1
echo 'pvar="password"' >> /tmp/testfile1
. /tmp/testfile1
rm /tmp/testfile1
```

After running the above script, the variables aren't loaded for the main shell.

Then I tried doing the same, but using a pre-made function in my `.bashrc` file, like so:
.bashrc file:

```
loadfunc() {
    echo "loading variables from /tmp/testfile1"
    . /tmp/testfile1
}
export -f loadfunc
```

Now this actually works, the `loadfunc` function can be called inside the script because of the `export -f loadfunc` since the `echo` will appear, like so:

```
echo 'uvar="user"' >> /tmp/testfile1
echo 'pvar="password"' >> /tmp/testfile1
loadfunc
rm /tmp/testfile1
```

But the problem is that, again, the variables aren't available to the main shell after sourcing the file.

Does anybody have any idea how this can be done?
This has to be done in one script though.

Comment: A process cannot change the environment of its parent process.

Comment: @cyrus so is there any viable workaround?

Comment: One workaround would be to call the script from your rc file (e.g. `.bashrc`) populating your temporary file with the variable assignments and then source the temporary file from your rc file. Why do you need these variables as part of your shell?.

Comment: One standard way to do this is to `source` (or `.`) the script (so it runs directly in the main shell) -- but note that the script must be valid in whatever shell the user happens to be using. Another is for the script to print declaration commands, and use `eval "$(/path/to/script)"` in the main shell -- but getting the syntax right for definitions that contain weird characters (which passwords tend to do) can be tricky (and again you need to worry about which shell the user is running).

Answer (score 0):

Lots of utilities that have to change your environment, like `nvm` for changing node versions, and pythons `venv` wrapper I think, so something like this:

installation-file.sh

```sh
function load_the_vars {
  uvar=user
  pvar=$1 # set this from an argument
}
```

and that function can do all kinds of dynamic stuff, and even take command line arguments

and then

```sh
$ source vars.sh # source the file to load the function
$ load_the_vars new-password
$ # and then the vars are set
$ echo $uvar $pvar
user new-password
```

you can source `vars.sh` in your .bashrc so that it is always installed and then you can call the function that it defines any time.

after you source a file and define the function, you can look at the definition like this:

```
$ type load_the_vars
load_the_vars is a function
load_the_vars () 
{ 
    uvar=user;
    pvar=$1
}
```

---

Otherwise, you can just do it inline in a bash file, and source the file when you need it:

action-file.sh

```sh
uvar=user
pvar=password
```

```
$ source action-file.sh
$ echo $uvar $pvar
user password
```

if you need the variables exported to get passed into another program that you run, then export them in the file your source or the function your define